# Self referenced MySql table with conditions on parent and child

Tags: mysql

I have a table on Mysql with self reference parent/child records:

```
myTable

id    |    parent_id   |  text_1 |   text_2
```

I need a query with this pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE parent_id=-1 
AND IT HAS AT LEAST ONE CHILD 
AND text_1 != 'something'
AND child.text_2 != 'somethingElse'
```

here **AND IT HAS AT LEAST ONE CHILD** Means: there is at least one row that it's parent_id equals with the id of the row that you are finding.

What is the conversion of this pseudocode in MySql. The query for Laravel eloquent would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if an item has children, left join the table to itself on the parent/child relationship.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM myTable a
LEFT JOIN myTable b
    ON a.id = b.parent_id
WHERE (NOT b.id IS NULL) AND
    a.id = -1 AND
    a.text_1 <> 'something' AND
    b.text_2 <> 'somethingElse'
```

Comment: @Strawberry - LOL

Comment: That's right Strawberry. It just needs a little editing: a.text_1 and b.text_2